# comparing class instances or object not working in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my first and I am new in Python.
I am trying to create program that gathers the info of the release of .Net Framework then compares it with value of the variable d 460805 which is an object of this class

Here are the steps taken:
Create Class DotNetVersion that can compare the value of variable `d` that I define it at the end of this code with the  value a.getdotnetinfo(subkeyname) which evaluate to 460805 on my PC 
Create Class look_get_DotNet_version that will take the machine then define the function that gets the value of the registry of `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Client` and returns it to be printed

## Code below:

```
import json
import os
import sys

try:
    from winreg import*
except:
    print ("Unable to import _winreg module! Please Check your python installation.")
    exit(-1)


class DotNetVersion(object):

    def __init__(self,release):
        self.release = release


    def __eq__(self, other): 
        if not isinstance(other, a.getdotnetinfo(subkeyname)):

            print("not an instance")
            return NotImplemented
        else:
            print("it is an instance")



    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.release}'



class look_get_DotNet_version(object):

    def __init__(self,machine):

        try:
            if machine == None:
                self.lm_hive = OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, '')
            else:
                self.lm_hive = ConnectRegistry(machine, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)

        except WindowsError as e:
            print (e)
            exit(-2)



    def getdotnetinfo(self, subkeyname):
        output = None
        try:
            if subkeyname:
                subkey = OpenKey(self.lm_hive, subkeyname)
                release = QueryValueEx(subkey, 'Release')[0]
                output = DotNetVersion(release)

        except Exception as e:
            print (e)
            pass

        return output
```

### What I defined and class call:

I create a variable `subkeyname`:

```
subkeyname = r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Client'
```

Set the machine to None:

```
machine = None
```

Created `a` as follow to set the `self.lm_hive` as `OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, '')`:

```
a = look_get_DotNet_version(machine)
```

Create a string of value 460805:

```
d="460805"
```

Create d as instance of class DotNetVersion:

```
d = DotNetVersion(d)
```

Create b to output the value of the version:

```
b = a.getdotnetinfo(subkeyname)
print(b)
```

Run the compare b which is of value of 460805 with d of value 460805:

```
print(look_get_DotNet_version.__eq__(b,d))
```

### The output is:

```
460805
NotImplemented
```

I am stuck at this point where the `__eq__`, from the below snippet, it should say it is an instance because `other` which is d is equal to `a.getdotnetinfo(subkeyname)`

```
def __eq__(self, other):

    if not isinstance(other, a.getdotnetinfo(subkeyname)):

        print("not an instance")
        return NotImplemented
    else:
        print("it is an instance")
```

or if you can help me to guide how can I compare the release in this situation.

The long term vision of this program that if it doesn't match to download the .NET framework of 4.7 and install it on the machine.

All your help is appreciated and please let me know if you need any clarification.

I know formatting look terrible but I will work on it

Comment: You should return `True` or `False` from your `__eq__()` method.

Comment: What attributes do you want to compare?

Comment: I think you are making this more complicated than necessary. Just compare `release == "460805`.

Comment: `look_get_DotNet_version.__eq__(b,d)` Don't call `__eq__()` directly. Use the `==` operator instead.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `isinstance(other, a.getdotnetinfo(subkeyname))`?

Answer (score 0):

You are making this significantly more complicated than necessary by creating a class to wrap the version string. You can just as easily return the version string directly from `getdotnetinfo()` and compare it directly:

```
    def getdotnetinfo(self, subkeyname):
        output = None
        try:
            if subkeyname:
                subkey = OpenKey(self.lm_hive, subkeyname)
                release = QueryValueEx(subkey, 'Release')[0]
                return release 
        except Exception as e:
            print (e)
```

Then to use it:

```
a = look_get_DotNet_version(machine)

d="460805"
b = a.getdotnetinfo(subkeyname)
print(b)
print(b == d)

if b == d:
    # do something
```

If you insist on creating a custom class and overriding `__eq__()`, you first need to clearly define what equality means. In this case, I think you want two instances to be equal if they have the same `release` attribute:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.release == other.release
```

There is no need to overthink this.

Be sure that you use the `==` operator. You should never call `__eq__()` directly:

```
a = look_get_DotNet_version(machine)
d = DotNetVersion("460805")
b = a.getdotnetinfo(subkeyname)
print(b)
print(b == d)
if b == d:
    # do something
```

Comment: Well-behaved rich-comparison dunder methods should return `NotImplemented` though, so that isn't really bad if you are going that route

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I assume you only returned `NotImplemented` if the dunder method is, in fact, not implemented because it doesn't make sense for your class. Is that correct?

Comment: No, you need to type check the idea is, check the type, if you support it, do it, so `if isinstance(other, DotNetVersion): return self.release == other.release else: return NotImplemented` then, the actual implementation checks basically, `result = obj1.__eq__(obj2); if result is NotImplemented, result = ob2.__eq__(ob1), if result is NotIMplemented: raise TypeError` etc So consider `float.__eq__(0.0, None)`

Comment: @Code-Apprentice   I appreciate your help, I test it out now I can do the comparison using Print but when i am running the print command it is giving me false, i expect to give me true. I can send you the .py if you want to try it

Comment: I got this figure out when comparing d and b, b is already an integer, so I converted d to integer and now the compare is working.
Thanks so much for the contribution and help

Comment: @SvetlanaofVodianova No, in Python unlike Java, it is not required to implement `__hash__()` if you implement `__eq__()`. Noteable example: `dict`.